# Problems with my log in and register scripts

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, authentication

I am getting pretty annoyed with an issue with my log in and register scripts that are not working. The funniest thing is that for two weeks ago I used the exact same scripts in another website in another server and it works awesome!

**ISSUE**

When I try to register or log in I am not redirected to the page I was supposed to be. On register.php the user gets registered (I can see it on the database) but I am not redirected to the login.php, instead the script get's crashed on the message "redirecting you to xxxx.php". [Here you can read my scripts](http://forums.devshed.com/php-faqs-and-stickies-167/how-to-program-a-basic-but-secure-login-system-using-891201.html).

I took contact with my server (ipage) and asked if something was going wrong with their system. I got 3 different and crossed answers:

1st) I was able to replicate your issue. I did some preliminary troubleshooting and was not able to get to the root cause of the issue.
2nd) They answered me later that they were able to register new users and log in with no problem
3rd) Final answer was that the issue was on my scripts

I am not sure of what is happening here because the scripts are not working (on the opposite to what they say). I wonder if they are lying because they simply are no good or can't find out the cause of the problem. Anyway, the error log says the following:

*"20131014T033118: url.org/folder/login.php 
PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosweb26a/b366/ipg.domainname/folder/folder/common.php:1) in /hermes/bosweb26a/b366/ipg.domainname/folder/folder/common.php on line 77 "*

Line 77 is: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');. If I take it out, the error just passes on to another line...

Presuming that I already debugged the scripts and found no error, could this be due to the server's quality? (PHP version f.i.?)

Comment: I just copy/pasted the tutorial locally, and it is working as intended. What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: My server has 5.3.13. This should be working...

Comment: Now KCFinder is not working... exact same issue, everything is as is on their documentation but it still doesn't work... I am starting to think that it is a server problem... Later this week I will try to reproduce the system on another server and test it...

Comment: After more investigation, if I copy/paste the script as-is, I get no warnings. If I echo 4096 or more characters on the first line of common.php, I trigger the warning. Content _must_ be being sent to the browser, and your log is telling me it's on line 1 of common.php ("output started at ..." is pointing at the culprit).

Comment: I did not mention that the website has it's own domain but does not have a own server. I have it located on another server, should this have any influence?

Answer (score 0):

You can put `session_start()` on the first line ok common.php

Comment: Tried it and not working... besides, why and how come does it work exactly like in the tut on my previous website?

Answer (score 0):

Just switch round `session_start` and `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8')`:

```
// This initializes a session.  Sessions are used to store information about 
// a visitor from one web page visit to the next.  Unlike a cookie, the information is 
// stored on the server-side and cannot be modified by the visitor.  However, 
// note that in most cases sessions do still use cookies and require the visitor 
// to have cookies enabled.  For more information about sessions: 
// http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php 
session_start(); 

// This tells the web browser that your content is encoded using UTF-8 
// and that it should submit content back to you using UTF-8 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Have you got a space before `<?php` as the top of `common.php`? If you do you need to remove it.

Comment: It's not working and I am getting the exact same error, both on the website and on the error log. :( Besides, why would I need to do this now when it worked fine on my previous website?

Comment: have you got a space before `<?php` as the top of `common.php`? If you do you need to remove it.

Comment: Or a line break. Check for any content or whitespace before the opening php tag in login.php AND common.php. Having said that, the warning in the logs suggest it is the `header()` call on line 77 of login.php that is causing problems, not rogue whitespace.

Comment: I did check and I had a white space on the common.php. I removed it but still the same issue... I don't understand how come it works perfect on one website and not at all in another. Could it be the server's PHP version?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `session_start()` is called before calling `header()`, or echoing any content. So in login.php, you need to make sure `session_start()` is either at the top of the page, or you need to move it so it is called much earlier in your script, at least before any `header()` calls.

Comment: "so it is called much earlier in your script, at least before any header() calls." - That is already done since the very beginning...

Comment: The PHP warning message you posted is saying that something on line 77 has prevented PHP from being able to start the session. A session cannot be started if there has already been output sent or headers set. If line 77 definitely contains nothing but that header call, it must be being called before you are calling session_start().

Comment: I don't understand, that is exactly what I am doing... It's copy/paste from the tutorial, I just changed the values for the username, db name, etc...

Comment: The tutorial is wrong, the `header()` call needs to come after the `session_start()` call. Does it work if you move the `session_start()` call to the very first thing in common.php?

Comment: No it doesn't. I get error on the line 2 which is exactly session_start() or if I switch only the order of session_start() with header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); I will get the same error...

Comment: It most certainly does. See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) on `session_start()`. One of the notes says "To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.". This includes header calls. It will generate a warning otherwise, which is what you are seeing in your logs. If you have run this exact code before with no errors, it means you had your `error_reporting()` level set to not show warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Personally i use `ob_start();` after the `session_start();` and `ob_flush()` at the end of the file;